# How to print HTTPBody using alamofire multipart request Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

How to print HTTPBody using alamofire multipart request Swift

Right now I am trying with below code but app crash on this line

```
print("HTTP Body \(String(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "HTTP body not found")")
```

> I am using multipart request

I want to print like this HTTPBody

```
// HTTP body: foo=bar&baz[]=a&baz[]=1&qux[x]=1&qux[y]=2&qux[z]=3
```

Comment: Try to use this Network Logger library: https://github.com/konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
print(String(decoding: response.request?.httpBody ?? Data(), as: UTF8.self))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this code is not working with a multipart request, I want to print HTTP body for a multipart request.